# my master dns is running on Debian, can i configure rhel as slave DNS

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, redhat, bind

I  need to configure a slave dns on RHEL 3 , but my master DNS is Debian 7, is it possible to configure dns on such manner if possible kindly help me on this

Comment: ...redhat *3*? Why?!

Comment: Even if he is talking about RHEL 3 WHY?!?

Comment: Red Hat 3?! Do you mean RHEL 3? Actually it doesn't matter: Upgrade it now! Both are EOL.

Comment: yes it is RHEL3

Comment: RHEL 3? Please please let it die.

Comment: @faker Debian Wheezy is not EOL. But RHEL 3 is most certainly long dead. It has no business being used for any new projects at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton with both I meant RH3 and RHEL3. I'm not a Debian guy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on using BIND on both, then it will be compatible.   The standards related to zone transfers have been stable for a decade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Be careful with the IP address on the master & slave DNS servers, so you might end send it the zones to another server. Check this http://www.howtoforge.com/installation-of-bind-as-a-secondary-slave-dns-server-on-centos